# the values not display with filter AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello I have a very long json more than 2000 elements I return it from php but I can't seem to display it
I adapt the display with my form or the other possibility works
the html Code

```
<input list="professeur" ng-model="searched2" id="search" name="search"  />
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search">
    <td>{{item.nom || item.id_disque}}</td>
    <td>{{item.lesson ||item.id_projet || item.chemin}}</td>
```

angularjs requete

```
$http.get("search.php?type_recherche="+type_de_recherche+"&value_recherche="+recherche+"&type_resultat="+type_de_resultat)
        .then(
            function(response){
                $scope.data=response.data
                value_recherche.value = "";
                console.log(response.data);
            }, 
            function(response){ 
            }
            );
```

the json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLf53.png)

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: no error in the console I cannot display the content of the JSON when it should be displayed

Comment: you can test first if `data` gets binded to HTML with a {{data.length}}

Comment: I just tried and it does not display anything and I tried with the request that works it displays well

Comment: ok the problem is the filter when it is present it no longer displays the json but it is present in the console